# p value when use GEE to evaluate the trend

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I know that `ee.Reducer.linearFit()` in google earth engine is a very common function used when evaluating trends, but GEE doesn't seem to be able to tell us the significance of the trend being evaluated. I'm not sure if this necessarily fails to get a p-value if the `ee.Reducer.linearFit()` function is used. I'm still new to GEE, can anyone give me some advice?